# MVC and JQuery datepicker - Wrong dateformat on initialization of datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, date, datepicker

The title might not describe my problem very accurately, but I couldn't find a better way to describe it shortly.

Here's my problem; I'm creating an MVC application, and using the JQuery datepicker to make the pick a date from an input field. Whenever the action loads (/Report/Index), the first time, I need the date to be set to whatever is in the model. It does load the date, but the date format is incorrect: `dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss`, though I'm changing the dateformat in the initialization function of the datepicker, just as seen here:

```
$('.datefield').datepicker({ dateformat: 'dd/mm/yy'});
```

Whenever i change the date within this input field, the format is correct.

How can I make the date from the model, to be the correct date format whenever the action loads?

**Markup**

```
<div>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StartDate, new { @class = "datefield" })
</div>
```

**Model snippet (StartDate)**

```
public class ReportViewModel{

    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
}
```

*If you need to see more code than this, you're more than welcome to ask*

Comment: Try `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StartDate, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "datefield" })`

Comment: @StephenMuecke already tried that. It won't let me, and gives me an error. I guess I can't use methods like that within the helper.

Comment: Of course you can. And what error are your getting? (the code in my last comment works fine)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Oh wait sorry, I read your comment wrong (thought you meant `ToString("dd/mm/yyyy")`. Using your method gives the following output `"23-02-2016"`. Is there a way for me to change the dash to a forward slash?

Comment: `"{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"` does not out put `23-02-2016` - it outputs `23/02/2016` - check you code again for errors/typos

Comment: @StephenMuecke Strange, it does for me. Nevermind, I get the point of the format. This is another issue. If you make the answer to this question, I'll mark it as the answer. EDIT: Found the issue, appreciate the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `TextBoxFor()` method to use the [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.textboxfor(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.TextBoxFor%60%602%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper%7B%60%600%7D,System.Linq.Expressions.Expression%7BSystem.Func%7B%60%600,%60%601%7D%7D,System.String,System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary%7BSystem.String,System.Object%7D%29) that includes a format string

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StartDate, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "datefield" })
```